# Script gives 1899 for the timestamp year. How to fix it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

The following code was almost exactly what I was looking for to timestamp the adjacent cell after being edited. However, I need to incorporate the currnet date as well as time. The code below gives a date "1899".

What do I need to edit or is there a better code?

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if ( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if ( r.getColumn() == 13 ) { //checks the column
            var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
            if ( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
                var time = new Date();
                time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
                nextCell.setValue(time);
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display date along with the timestamp, then look at this line:

```
time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
```

You can set this to whatever you like, in the year case try this:

```
time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
```

If you are only concerned about displaying the year, then replace the `MM/DD/yy` info with just `yyyy`